# Why not let your child fall asleep while being held, rocked, fed a bottle, or while nursing?

Tags: pre-schooler, teeth

From: https://aasm.org/children-who-grind-their-teeth-are-more-likely-to-have-problems-in-school-be-withdrawn-from-others/

> Do not let your child fall asleep while being held, rocked, fed a bottle, or while nursing.

Why? How is this related to teeth grinding or bad sleep?

Milk/Sugar can cause tooth decay, I know, but what's the problem in being held or rocked?

Child's age: 4 years

Comment: This is a recommendation on how to encourage good sleep habits; there is nothing that says bruxism will result. I'm closing this because the question is unclear. A user should not need to read a paper linked to in the question in order to answer it. It would be like saying, "What is this insect," without including a picture of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People have been subjected to far worse in the course of human history yet turned out fine, even spectacularly.  The only problem addressed in the report in the link is the lack of a problem to address in a report for an author whose career is to address problems in reports.

Hold your child and risk teeth grinding.  Don't hold your child and risk attachment and intimacy issues.  They'll be grinding their teeth anyways when they're studying for finals, writing a dissertation, developing a presentation, or  otherwise engaged in stressful activities inherent to the high-achievement every parent dreams to instill in their progeny.  You should no more avoid holding your child than you should raise them for underachievement so they aren't burdened by the stresses that come with the pursuit of achievement because they might grind their teeth.

Comment: I really like the sarcasm here.